# How to make BottomNavigationItem fill space available?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make BottomNavigation with text appearing from right side of selected item. How can I make BottomNavigationItem fill available space or move other items, to prevent text from wrapping?

[here's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKwOq.jpg)

Tried this, but didn't work:

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(
    items: List<BottomNavItem>,
    navController: NavController,
    onItemClick: (BottomNavItem) -> Unit
) {
    val backStackEntry = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    BottomNavigation(
        modifier = Modifier,
        elevation = 0.dp,
        backgroundColor = light
    ) {
        items.forEach{
            val selected = it.screen_route == backStackEntry.value?.destination?.route
            BottomNavigationItem(
                selected = selected,
                selectedContentColor = primary_color,
                unselectedContentColor = shaded,
                onClick = { onItemClick(it) },
                icon = {
                    Row(
                        modifier = if (selected) Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(horizontal = 15.dp)
                        else Modifier
                            .padding(horizontal = 15.dp)
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = it.icon,
                            contentDescription = it.title,
                            tint = if (selected) primary_color else shaded,

                            )
                        if (selected){
                            Text(
                                text = it.title,
                                color = primary_color,
                                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                                fontSize = 20.sp,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 2.dp).align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                                overflow = TextOverflow.Visible
                            )
                        }
                    }

                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check solution from [Jetsnack](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/84dc6417dfbd6408f498d71afcc1272087c6b3d7/Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/home/Home.kt?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container%2C%20div%5Bitemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FSoftwareSourceCode%22%5D%20main%2C%20%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D#L107) sample app. I think this is the same behavior you want to achieve.